# Creating a custom overlay onto map of United States to be used in d3.js. Choropleth

Tags: javascript, d3.js, choropleth

I would like to add a layer to a simple United States map that defines my company's regions. For the most part these regions are a combination of states but one region uses half of a state (TX).

What are some resources to create custom lines on top of a US map so I can mouseover and highlight entire regions? I will be using d3 and whatever libraries are relevant.

Essentially I want to create my own map using an existing template, while still maintaining the state lines. Not sure where to start. Thanks, all.

Comment: As a *tutorial* question, this question is off-topic for S.O. However, here is an idea: get the GeoJSON (or TopoJSON, you didn't specify it) with the counties of US (like this: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4122298), define the counties your company uses in Texas and merge those counties in a path.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thanks for replying. What would be the proper place to ask this?

Comment: Mmm, it's complicated. Here at S.O. we deal with code problems, but you have no code, you're actually seeking for one (thus, you clearly need a tutorial). I'm not sure if any SE site suits you... well, leve the question here, let's see if someone helps you. Meanwhile, this link can be helpful: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9885854 And also this: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9867796